# How to insert xml data from URL into SQL Server 2008 database by call stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I'm a beginner, I want to fetch data from Zoho Crm and then insert it into a SQL Server database by calling a stored procedure in C#

My way :

1. Using Zoho API whit URL (it works well)
2. Using `XmlDocument` to load XML data from URL above (it work well)

My code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=mytoken&scope=crmapi&lastModifiedTime=2011-05-27%2000:00:00&fromIndex=1482&toIndex=1682");
```

Now how to insert to database using stored procedure?

Data example :

Note : the number of FL element maybe difference in each row

```
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords">
  <result>
    <Accounts>
      <row no="1">
        <FL val="ACCOUNTID">380198000000068646</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">380198000000052013</FL>
        <FL val="Account Owner">Mai Tran</FL>
        <FL val="Account Name">Trung Tâm Nghiên Cứu & Phát Triển Chế Biến Dầu Khí</FL>
        <FL val="Website">www.pvpro.com.vn</FL>
        <FL val="Industry">Energy, Oil & Gas</FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Created By">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By">Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="Created Time">2011-05-04 09:49:11</FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time">2012-02-24 14:41:48</FL>
        <FL val="Billing Street">4 Nguyen Thong St</FL>
        <FL val="District">Q.3</FL>
        <FL val="City">Hồ Chí Minh</FL>
      </row>
      <row no="2">
        <FL val="ACCOUNTID">380198000000068644</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Account Owner">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="Account Name">Tổng Cty Tư Vấn Thiết Kế</FL>
        <FL val="Phone">6297 1778</FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Created By">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By">Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="Created Time">2011-05-04 09:49:11</FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time">2012-02-24 14:40:42</FL>
        <FL val="Billing Street">Parkson Tân Sân Nhất</FL>
        <FL val="District">Tân Bình</FL>
        <FL val="City">Hồ Chí Minh</FL>
        <FL val="Alternative Names">PV Engineering</FL>
      </row>
      <row no="3">
        <FL val="ACCOUNTID">380198000000068642</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">380198000000052015</FL>
        <FL val="Account Owner">Trang Do Thi</FL>
        <FL val="Account Name">CTY TNHH BẢO HIỂM NHÂN THỌ VIỆT NAM</FL>
        <FL val="Phone">9 101 660</FL>
        <FL val="Account Type">Active</FL>
        <FL val="Industry">Financial Services</FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Created By">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By">Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="Created Time">2011-05-04 09:49:11</FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time">2012-04-27 11:02:25</FL>
        <FL val="Billing Street"> Tôn Đức Thắng P.Bến Nghé</FL>
        <FL val="Phone 2">9 101 659</FL>
        <FL val="District">Q.1</FL>
        <FL val="City">Hồ Chí Minh</FL>
        <FL val="Key Contact">Duy Nhật</FL>
        <FL val="Partner Type">Loyal Partner</FL>
        <FL val="Collection">1859353554</FL>
        <FL val="Alternative Names">Việt Nam</FL>
      </row>
      <row no="4">
        <FL val="ACCOUNTID">380198000000068638</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">380198000000052015</FL>
        <FL val="Account Owner">Trang Do Thi</FL>
        <FL val="Account Name">Cty TNHH Gia Dụng Phương Gia</FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Created By">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">380198000000041003</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By">Bach Tran Phuong</FL>
        <FL val="Created Time">2011-05-04 09:49:11</FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time">2012-02-24 13:52:25</FL>
        <FL val="Billing Street">Cao Thang</FL>
        <FL val="District">Q.3</FL>
        <FL val="City">Hồ Chí Minh</FL>
        <FL val="Alternative Names">Home Appliances ltd</FL>
      </row>
    </Accounts>
  </result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1**: create your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoreXmlData (@XmlData XML)
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourXmlTable(XmlColumnName)
    VALUES(@XmlData)
END
```

This assumes you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer, and you're storing your XML in a column that is really of datatype `XML`. Adapt table and column name as needed to match **your** situation.

**Step 2**: from C#, call your stored procedure using standard ADO.NET classes:

```
string sqlStmt = "dbo.StoreXmlData";  // name of your stored procedure

// here, you need to use *YOUR* connection string instead of my demo one...    
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=test;integrated security=SSPI;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
{
    // make sure to tell ADO.NET you're about to call a stored procedure!
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define the parameter and set its value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourData", SqlDbType.Xml);
    cmd.Parameters["@YourData"].Value = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;

    // standard ADO.NET - open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

That's really all there is!

**Update:** OK, so you want to actually shred the XML into individual columns - in that case, you need to do something like this in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoreXmlData (@XmlData XML)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourDataTable(RowNo, AccountID, OwnerID, AccountOwner)
        SELECT
            RowNo = Acc.value('@no', 'int'),
            AccountID = Acc.value('(FL[@val="ACCOUNTID"])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
            OwnerID = Acc.value('(FL[@val="SMOWNERID"])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
            AccountOwner = Acc.value('(FL[@val="Account Owner"])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
            -- and so on to grab all the items you need
        FROM
            @XmlData.nodes('/response/result/Accounts/row') AS Resp(Acc)
END
```

Comment: Thaks marc_s, I'm coding follow your idea

Comment: but how to put elements to talbe column exactly, e.g : Key contact, Alternative name, because only row =3 have Ky contact or only row = 2,3,4 have alternative name in My example XML data

Comment: @Hainlp: OK - but you want to store the XML elements into separate columns of a table - right? That's a whole new question to ask! Yes, it's totally possible - you'd need to tell us more about how that table looks like and which attribute needs to go into what column...

Comment: @Hainlp: updated my response to include code to "shred" the XML into pieces and store those separately. You'll need to extend this to get everything you need, and store them into the correct columns.

Comment: @Mac_s : It works well, but any element FL value has '&', it has error Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Procedure StoreXmlData, Line 0
XML parsing: line 47, character 54, illegal name character. e.g : <FL val="Account Name">Trung Tâm Nghiên Cứu & Phát Triển Chế Biến Dầu Khí</FL>    How can i fix it

Comment: @Hainlp: you need to replace those `&` with `&amp;` before inserting the data

Comment: @Mac_s : Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I can't insert if the content is Vietnamese language. Have any way to fix it

Comment: @Hainlp: are you columns where you store the data into all of type `NVARCHAR` ?

Comment: i just do it. I change your code : add "N" in store procedure (Acc.value(N'(FL[@val="ACCOUNTID"])[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'AccountID',) and OuterXml in C#(cmd.Parameters["@XmlData"].Value = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;). Thank you very much for hard support